# Share tomcat/webapps

Tags: tomcat, redhat, samba

I need share  /var/lib/tomcat/webapps with Samba 4.1.1 in order to make easy the deploy process.

If I use directly the target path in samba configuration

```
[webapps]
        path = /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/
        browseable = yes
```

obtain this errore

```
[2016/08/10 11:06:13.779626,  0] ../source3/smbd/service.c:792(make_connection_snum)
  canonicalize_connect_path failed for service webapps, path /usr/share/tomcat/webapps
```

If I try browse the /var/lib folder

```
[webapps]
        path = /var/lib/
        browseable = yes
        guest ok = yes
```

I can't see the tomcat folder. Change folder permissions doesn't resolve the problem. My distribution is Red Hat 7.0.

It seems that Samba hide some folder ma the logic is not clear.

Any idea?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the answer.
I solve the problem disabling SELinux.

Answer (score 0):

By the output I'm guessing that your **/var/lib/tomcat/webapps** folder is in fact some kind of link to **/usr/share/tomcat/webapps**

You should either correct the path, or add some more configuration options to allow samba to browse symlinks

```
[global]
unix extensions = no

[webapps]
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
```